# Opening app on notification click?

Tags: android, notifications

I would like to **open my app when the user clicks on notification**, if it is not in the foreground.

So far i got this:

```
private void adNotification(Ad ad) {

    PendingIntent dummyIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(), Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, SplashScreen.class);
    Store storeFromAd = ad.getStoreFromAd();
    notificationIntent.putExtra("uzlet", new Gson().toJson(storeFromAd));
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon).setAutoCancel(true).setContentTitle(ad.ad_title)
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(ad.ad_text)).setContentText(ad.ad_short_text);
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(dummyIntent);

    //Checks whether the application is in foreground.
    if (MainActivity.isInFront) {
        Log.i("isInFront-serviceCheck", "isInFront = true");
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(dummyIntent);
    }
    else {
        Log.i("isInFront-serviceCheck", "isInFront = false");
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    }
    int notifID = Integer.parseInt(ad.ad_id);
    mNotificationManager.notify(notifID, mBuilder.build());
}
```

**My activity has an** `isInFront` boolean variable:

```
    @Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    isInFront = true;
    Log.i("isInFront-onResume", "isInFront = true");
}
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    isInFront = false;
    Log.i("isInFront-onDestroy", "isInFront = false");

}
```

Well, my problem is:

Of course, it is working when you click on the notification immediately, but for example:

1. My app is in the foreground, the `isInFront` variable is true.
2. I got a notification, the notification builder builds it with the dummy intent, to do nothing.
3. Instead of clicking the notification, i close the app.
4. Now i click the notification, and the app is not opening because the notification builder was build it while the isInFront variable was true.

So the problem is, the intent for the notification is *not holding the current state* of the application, it is *holding that state when it has been sent to the device.*

How could i make this work? Any ideas?

Comment: You can try to clear the notification if app is in background.

Comment: Other wise you have to open the app through the notification click, if app is in background.